# UIBezierpath is not drawing a smooth image

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I want to create a custom button in swift and the result is not quite satisfying. UIBezierpath is not drawing a smooth path. Please see image and code below.

```
let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 156, 60), byRoundingCorners:.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(200, 200))
```

[image: rendered result: image1]

After playing around a little bit, I found that moving the path down and right 1 point and shrinking the rectangle size by 1 will solve the problem. but I don't like this solution, I don't think this is the correct way of doing it. And I feel like the frame is clipping my image. Can someone help me with this??

```
let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(1, 1, 154, 59), byRoundingCorners:.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(200, 200))
```

[image: rendered result: image2]

the whole CustomButton Subclass:

```
import UIKit

class DesignableButtons: UIButton {
    let black = UIColor(red: 33/255, green: 33/255, blue: 33/255, alpha: 1.0) /* #212121 */

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.setTitle("Go to Google", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "GT Walsheim", size: 14)
        self.setTitleColor(black, forState: .Normal)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Selected)
        self.titleLabel!.alpha = 1.0
    }

    let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 156, 60), byRoundingCorners:.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(200, 200))

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        black.setStroke()
        roundRect.stroke()
        if highlighted {
            black.setFill()
            roundRect.fill()
        }
    }

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post all of your drawing code? Also, does this reproduce on a physical device? Sometimes this happens on the simulator if you're not zoomed to 100%.

Comment: yes the same thing does happen on my physical iphone6.

Comment: `override func drawRect` No. It is not permitted to override `drawRect` for a UIButton. You need to construct a background image and set the button's background image and let _it_ do the drawing in its own way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0, 0, 156, 60), 1, 1), byRoundingCorners:.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(200, 200))
```

**EDITED**

or you can also do this to do it more reusable, this in your `layoutSubviews`

```
let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectInset(self.frame, 1, 1), byRoundingCorners:.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(200, 200))
```

Instead of

```
let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 156, 60), byRoundingCorners:.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(200, 200))
```

the `CGRectInset` function create a rect inside your original rect,

> Returns a rectangle that is smaller or larger than the source
>   rectangle, with the same center point.

**EDITED**
you can put this in your `init` to fix the visualization issue

```
self.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale //SUPPORT RETINA
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Thank you for your help! I looked at the documentation of CGRectInset, what is does is shrinking/expanding the size of the rectangle. In this case shrinking it by 1 point won't make a huge difference. However, that means it is not the exact same size though, that won't be accepted when it comes to production.

Comment: Its your bezier path who is modified, not the original button, what you means with "that won't be accepted when it comes to production."?

Comment: i mean in a company settings, to work with a design team, the UI needs to be pixel accurate. Shrinking a button by 1 pixel sometimes may not be accepted by the design team.

Comment: I told you that we are not modifying our button size only the UIBezierPath to make your border, your button had the same size ;), If this answer resolves your problem can you marked as accepted?

Comment: Sorry Reinier, I might be annoying. I understand your code won't modify the button size, but it modifies the appearance of the button. And that is what I am talking about, you are altering the design here. I am trying to look for a way to make it display correctly without shrinking the appearance of the button. I will accept your answer if there is really no way to do it. Once again thank you very much! : )

Comment: What you need is not a button with border of x pixels? rounded in the corners?

Comment: My answer was updated check if this resolves your main problem, regards

Comment: I found out stroke() draws outside of the UIBezierpath, so i would say it makes sense that shrinking the size of the UIBezierpath is the way to go.

Comment: What is a "visualization issue"?

Answer (score 1):

You have problem because lines was been clipped. When you drawing into **drawRect:** this happen an always. Try drawing outside **drawRect:**.

For example:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // some code
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = 200
    layer.borderWidth = 1
    layer.borderColor = black.CGColor
}
```

Or if you want using sublayers:

```
let borderLine = CAShapeLayer()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // some code
    frame = someFrame

    let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 156, 60), byRoundingCorners:.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(200, 200))
    borderLine.path = roundRect.CGPath
    borderLine.frame = bounds
    borderLine.strokeColor = black.CGColor
    borderLine.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    borderLine.lineWidth = 1

    layer.insertSublayer(borderLine, atIndex: 0)
}
```

Comment: Absolutely.  Clipping.

Comment: if you use this ´self.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale´ work with drawRect, I had updated my answer